# Microsoft Excel - Count the number of values each name has in a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I have a CSV file containing 100,000 rows.

Each row consists of information under a number of columns, such as "Date", "Page Accessed", "Page Type", "IP", "User Surname", "User Forename", "User Login", "Profile".

A few example rows may therefore look like:

```
A        B            C        D           E     F  G    H
18:48:42 Home Drive   web page 90.90.90.90 Gill  C  cgi  Teachers

20:48:42 Dashboard    web page 90.90.90.90 James R   rj   Teachers

22:48:42 Shared Drive web page 90.90.90.90 Gill  C   cgi  Teachers
```

These rows are an individual hit on our Virtual Learning Environment.

I would like to determine how many times each user has made a hit on our VLE.

As such, I would imagine that I need to get excel to count the number of times each `User Login` appears in the list of rows where `Teachers`, `Staff` or `Administrator` is the value for "Profile".

What's the easiest way of going about this?

**I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010.**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Pivot Table or advanced filtering would do exactly this

Comment: OK, that's great news, but I have no idea how to do either... :)

Comment: what version of excel are you using

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Excel 2010. I'll update my OP to clarify that!

Comment: You want to know how many unique values in column G appear when column H reads Teachers OR Staff OR Administrator?

Comment: I want to know how many times "cgi" under the "User Login" (which, say, is Column H) appears where the "User Profile" (say, column G) is equal to "Teachers" OR "Staff" OR "Administrator"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a Pivot Table:

Import your data into an Excel workbook and add the column titles if they are missing.

[image: picture of data in Excel with column titles]

Select a cell in the data and then click `Insert` -> `PivotTable`. A Create PivotTable dialog box will display. Make sure it correctly selected your entire range and click `OK`.

It will add a new sheet to your workbook with the PivotTable Field List displayed on the right. (If it is missing, click the Show `Field List` button on the `PivotTable Tools` `Options` tab.)

[image: PivotTable field list]

Drag fields to the appropriate part of the pivot table. i.e.

- Profile field to `Report Filter`
- User Login to `Row Lables`
- Date to `Values`  (After you move it, if it doesn't says `Count of Date`, then click the drop-down arrow, select `Value Field Settings` and change `Summarize Values By` to `Count`.)

That will give you a pivot table that looks like this.

[image: finished PivotTable]

To see a count for each Page Accessed, drag that field to `Column Labels`.

[image: altered PivotTable]

Feel free to explore and play with the PivotTable. Move things around, add more fields to `Row Labels` or `Column Labels` etc. If you can't figure out how to do a specific thing, ask another question.  :-)

Comment: Incredible post, many thanks! :) I'll look at this when I get to work tomorrow and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 1):

Without really seeing how it's set up and showing you how to do a pivot table, this formula will count for you.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(H:H,"cgi",G:G, {"administrator","staff","teachers"}))`

---

You could also select the data go to `insert - pivot table` and put `column H` as `row labels` and `column g` as `column labels` and put `column g` in the `sum of values` field, but change it to `count` instead of `sum` by clicking and selecting `value field settings`

Answer (score 0):

say Profile is in column H
code formula in column I2 "`=IF(OR(H2="tEACHERS",H2=sTAFF",h2="Admin")),1,0)` - this flags the entries you want with 1, 0 otherwise.
sum column I for total

Comment: This won't give me a running total of the number of hits each member of staff has made will it?

Comment: We need to count column G as well

Comment: How many users are you keeping track of? @Raystafarian is right that a pivot table would work for this. Or do a simple sumif formula on the users found in G in an adjacent column

Comment: There are around 80 members of staff.